# Checking for duplicate mysql data with bootstrap validator

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I created a signup form with the bootstrap validator and connected it to a MySQL database. I wish to prevent duplicate entries by checking for existing email data and returning a message through the bootstrap validator script. I am using the remote method but the problem is as soon as I start typing in the email field, I get the "Email has already been taken." message although the email may not already exist in the database or if it is only one alphabet typed. I also get data entries even when I have not submitted the form. I have searched online and realized most of the solutions exist for the jquery validation plugin but no the bootstrap validator. I need help, please. Here is my code:

**signup.php**

```
 <div class="signup-form">
 <h1>Sign up for free!</h1><br>

 <form id="form1" action="registration.php" class="loading-form" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name-input">Username</label>
  <input required type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" maxlength="100">
</div>    

  <label for="email-input">Email</label>
  <input required name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" title="An email is required">
</div>

<p>You accept our <a href="pages/terms.php" style="color: #337ab7;">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> by creating your account.</p>

<div class="form-group">
<!-- Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        username: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 
        characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z-' ]+$/,
                    message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical and number'
                },
                different: {
                    field: 'password',
                    message: 'The username and password cannot be the same as each other'
                }
            }
        },
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The email address is required'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'The email address is not a valid'
                },
                remote: {
                    message: 'The email address is already taken.',
                    url: "registration.php"
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
});
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php   
include ("connect.php");
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM registration where (email='$email')";
$check = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($checkrows>0) {
echo json_encode(FALSE);
}
else
{
echo json_encode(TRUE);
}

//insert results from the form input
$query = "INSERT INTO registration (username, email) VALUES('$username', '$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$num1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the the code that worked for me:

**registration**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$valid = true;
$message = '';

ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE);

include ("connect.php");
session_start();

//get the name and comment entered by user
$fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$fullName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fullName']);
$userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userName']);
$birthday = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['birthday']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

//insert results from the form input
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM registration where (email='$email')";
$check = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($checkrows > 0) {
   // If the email address exists in the table, the ``$valid`` variable define as false.
   $valid = false;
   $message = 'The email address exists.';
}
else
{

}

echo json_encode(
$valid ? array('valid' => $valid) : array('valid' => $valid, 'message' =>     $message)
);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your "registration.php" file, you're inserting the received info on database.

That's mean you're inserting duplicates, or even malformed email addresses. Also, if your javascript are trying to validate on each key press, you're inserting each letter. For example, if you're registering test@example.com, you have a register with email "t", another with "te", and so on until complete email.

Probably, that's the problem.

You need to do some modifications:
First of all: Perform some checks to the received values. For example, if checkrows > 0, never do the insert query. Also check email is well-formatted, on PHP side.

Additionally, try to write to the table only when the user click on submit.

You can use two files: One for check, and another one for validates and write result to table.

Answer (score 0):

First, your php file never stop script when an email address exists in the table. Because your if statement is problem.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$valid = true;
$message = '';

include ("connect.php");
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM registration where (email='$email')";
$check = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$checkrows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($checkrows > 0) {
   // If the email address exists in the table, the ``$valid`` variable define as false.
   $valid = false;
   $message = 'The email address exists.';
}
else
{
   // If the email address has not exists in the table, adds new record to database and $valid variable returns as true.
   //insert results from the form input
   $query = "INSERT INTO registration (username, email) VALUES('$username', '$email')";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   $num1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}

echo json_encode(
$valid ? array('valid' => $valid) : array('valid' => $valid, 'message' =>     $message)
);

?>
```

Please check remote.php demo file from official repo. https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/remote.php

Comment: Your script was helpful but I modified it a bit. I took out the insert query and put it in a separate php page. It works now!